# Does webmock auto detects `?` in the url

Tags: rspec, rspec-rails, webmock

I am using webmock for stubbing requests.
I stubbed a request using the following code.

```
stub_request(:delete, "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/1741/likes?access_token=this_is_a_test_token").to_return(body: "true")
```

And I get the following error :-

```
WebMock::NetConnectNotAllowedError:
       Real HTTP connections are disabled. Unregistered request: DELETE https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/1741/likes with body 'access_token=this_is_a_test_token' with headers {'Accept'=>'*/*', 'Content-Type'=>'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Date'=>'Sun, 19 Apr 2015 08:43:06 GMT', 'User-Agent'=>'FbGraph2 (0.5.0) (2.5.1, ruby 2.1.2 (2014-05-08))'}

       You can stub this request with the following snippet:

       stub_request(:delete, "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/1741/likes").
         with(:body => {"access_token"=>"this_is_a_test_token"},
              :headers => {'Accept'=>'*/*', 'Content-Type'=>'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Date'=>'Sun, 19 Apr 2015 08:43:06 GMT', 'User-Agent'=>'FbGraph2 (0.5.0) (2.5.1, ruby 2.1.2 (2014-05-08))'}).
         to_return(:status => 200, :body => "", :headers => {})

       registered request stubs:

       stub_request(:delete, "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/1741/likes?access_token=this_is_a_test_token")
```

It was working before when I used `http://...com/1741/likes` I just made a change in the stub request for adding a namespace `v2.0` and the test cases are broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've changed the URL that you're stubbing. You should stub using the message displayed with the query params specified in the `with` method arguments!